# How to shard using OrientDB

Tags: orientdb, distributed-database

How to achieve sharding on OrientDB?

Suppose I have three nodes viz. node1, node2 and node3. I have two clusers viz. zip_india, zip_usa.

Now I tried to set the servers up such that zip_india will be on node1 and node2 and zip_usa will be on node3.

I configured the default-distributed-db-config.json before creating the database. 
After I create the datbase, and connect other nodes a lot of other clusters are automatically being formed viz. _studio, _studio_node2, _studio_node3 etc.

Now, by connecting to node1, if I insert a record to zip_india cluster, I am able to see the replication happening even on node3. Is the data actually being stored on node3? Or is Orient actually fetching the data from node1 when I query node3 for the particular record in zip_india cluster?

Comment: I'm also looking for the same answer